# Vectan.m in Mathematica12 - returns VPValue instead of VP (same with SP etc)

Tags: symbolic

for years I was using Vectan.m to do analytical vector calculations.  There seem to be a problem in Mathematica 12 (on Mac). All loads well, but then instead of VP[a,b] it returns VPValue[a, b]:

### <<"~/Vectan.m";

### VECTAN, Version 1.1, (14.5.1997)
(C) Bernd Fiedler, Math. Inst., Univ. Leipzig, 1996
email: fiedler@rz.uni-leipzig.de
http://www.mathematik.uni-leipzig.de/MI/fiedler/fiedler.html

Load usage.m

Load def.m

Load deriv.m

Load utilitie.m

In:= DefineVector[{a, b}]

DefineVector::inf: Vector field Vect[a] has been established.

DefineVector::inf: Vector field Vect[b] has been established.

In:= VP[a, b]

Out:= VPValue[a, b]

Comment: Interesting. This does not seem like it is best addressed to the mma.SE site here, but rather should be fielded to the author of the package. As it is, this question is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The package is old, but was highly useful. It seems to be a conflict with the new version of Mathematica. The question is "how to fix it?".

Comment: What does `ValueQ[VPValue[a, b]]` give you?

Comment: Few are going to be willing to download a package — ***the OP should give a link to it at least*** — but that’s not necessarily a reason for closing on SE. I’d suggest: (1) Reinstall the package (and edit the question to report whether that fixed it). (2) Email the author, since he provided his email for a purpose. The web link is dead. So the author may be retired, may have moved to another institution, and may not be reachable.

Comment: ValueQ[VPValue[a, b]]  gives "True".

Comment: That's the reason it substitutes `VPValue[a,b]` for `VP[a,b]`.  According to [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ.html), `ValueQ` changed in V12.2. You should try changing all the calls `ValueQ[<whatever>]` to `Value[<whatever>, Method -> "Legacy"]` in the package. There are quite a few, I think.

Comment: Site tip: I didn't get notified of your reply.  Use @user to ensure notification (@MichaelE2 for me). The author of a post is always notified, and the @ is unnecessary (and often removed automatically).

Comment: @MichelE2: Thanks a lot! Changing ValueQ to Value did not help, but I just installed V12.1 and it works!!!